# Why is this code working and not the other one? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <input name="usrname" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <input name="comnts" type="text" placeholder="comments"/>
        <input id="btnButton" type="Submit" value="Click me"/>
</body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
           var refButton = document.getElementById("btnButton");
            refButton.onclick = function() {
                window.alert("Hi");
                //var name-"Bhuvanesh";
                //var Comment="Zack";
                //window.alert("Hello");
            }
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

> This code above works and the code below does not work

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <input name="usrname" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <input name="comnts" type="text" placeholder="comments"/>
        <input id="btnButton" type="Submit" value="Click me"/>
</body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
           var refButton = document.getElementById("btnButton");
            refButton.onclick = function() {
                //window.alert("Hi");
                var name-"Bhuvanesh"; //Edited from - to =
                var Comment="Zack";
                window.alert("Hello "+name);
            }
        };
    </script>
</html>
```

> I do not understand why the code below does not work. I have used window.onload to make sure the page renders first. Somehow the code does not seem to work. I am trying to make a simple page that can accept Name and comment from the textbox and display it on the webpage. I am relatively new to web development. Any help is appreciated.
>   Edit 1: This code below does not seem to work.`

```
var name=document.getElementByName("usrname");
            var Comment=document.getElementByName("comnts");
            document.write(name+ "wrote "+Comment);
```

Comment: This is a syntax error: `var name-"Bhuvanesh";`

Comment: You have a type, `=` instead of `-` in your assignment...

Comment: `var name-"Bhuvanesh";` should be `var name = "Bhuvanesh";`

Comment: `name-` instead of `name=`

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply that worked fine @Filburt thank you but why is that this code is not working?
var name=document.getElementByName("usrname");
             var Comment=document.getElementByName("comnts");
             document.write(name+ "wrote "+Comment);

Comment: You have a typo there also. `getElementByName` should be `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `getElementByName` is not a function. You can use `getElementsByName` (note the plural). This will return a collection rather than an element. More than this, you were fetching the entire element, not the value of the element like it seems you want. The following works for me:

```
var name = document.getElementsByName("usrname")[0].value;
var comment = document.getElementsByName("comnts")[0].value;
document.write(name + "wrote "+ comment);
```